# Cannot import 'name' error with pip3 on clean Ubuntu install

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I have a clean install of ubuntu 16.04 on an EC2 instance. I've gone ahead and upgraded the Python version from 3.5 to 3.7. Unfortunately, this seems to have rendered pip3 non-functional. Despite definitely having pip3 installed:

```
~$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

when I try to do anything with pip3, it shows the same error:

```
~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)
```

I have tried upgrading pip via

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and getting pip from source via

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

Neither has fixed the problem. Any ideas on what might be going on? I've managed to get replicate the error by undertaking the upgrade to 3.7 on a clean EC2 server, though I also was hitting the same thing on another EC2 instance when upgrading to 3.7. I'm guessing this has to do with ubuntu in that case--is there a reason that 3.7 isn't playing nicely with my pip?

Edit:
Suggested re-installing pip via

```
 python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

That yields the following error trace:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 48, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 108, in _build_session
    index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 559, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 144, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 737, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Try `python3.7 -m pip` a,d make sure there's nothing called `pip` in your folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the system pip has been corrupted, maybe try un-installing/re-installing pip via python3:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall
```

Comment: That returns an error (added the error output to the original question)

Answer (score 0):

Pip developers [say very clearly](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599):

> Only ever use your system package manager to upgrade the system pip

`pip3` can be configured for old python. Use `pythonx.x -m pip` instead so you're sure that you're installing packages for the right python version.

I suggest installing pip [the official way](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) . Deb pip packages will have very old pip, and it's hard to update them without breaking anything. If you installed something like `python3.7-pip` I suggest removing it.

PS: I hope that by upgrading python you mean installing 3.7 besides system 3.5, because replacing python3.5 will likely break something in your OS.